# flutter UI rendering Library Error in SliverGrid

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
body: Container(
    width: _maxScreenWidth,
    child: SafeArea(
      child:Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [

            Container(
                  height: 160.0,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0,horizontal: 15),

                    child: CustomScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      slivers: <Widget>[
                        SliverPadding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          sliver: _buildContent(urls),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                ),

          SizedBox(height: 20.0,)  ,

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),



SliverGrid _buildContent(List<String> urls) {
return SliverGrid(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
    maxCrossAxisExtent: 150,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
    crossAxisSpacing: 10,

  ),
  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return PortfolioGalleryImageWidget(urls: urls[index],
        onImageTap: () =>
            Navigator.push(context,
              _createGalleryDetail(urls, index),
            ),
      );
    },
    childCount: urls.length,
  ),

);
```

}

ERROR

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
SliverGeometry is not valid: The "scrollExtent" is negative.

## The RenderSliver that returned the offending geometry was: RenderSliverGrid#ee36d relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...  parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: SliverConstraints(AxisDirection.right, GrowthDirection.forward, ScrollDirection.idle, scrollOffset: 0.0, remainingPaintExtent: 371.4, crossAxisExtent: 110.0, crossAxisDirection: AxisDirection.down, viewportMainAxisExtent: 381.4, remainingCacheExtent: 621.4, cacheOrigin: 0.0)
...  geometry: SliverGeometry(scrollExtent: -10.0, hidden, maxPaintExtent: -10.0)
...    scrollExtent: -10.0
...    hidden
...    maxPaintExtent: -10.0
...  no children current live
The relevant error-causing widget was:
SliverGrid file:///Users/gagansingh/FlutterProjects/firebase_app/lib/fullImageView/PortfolioGallarySubPage.dart:441:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      SliverGeometry.debugAssertIsValid..verify (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:712:9)
#1      SliverGeometry.debugAssertIsValid. (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:721:13)
#2      SliverGeometry.debugAssertIsValid (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:751:6)
#3      RenderSliver.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1206:22)
#4      RenderObject.layout. (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1787:9)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderSliverGrid#ee36d relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...  parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: SliverConstraints(AxisDirection.right, GrowthDirection.forward, ScrollDirection.idle, scrollOffset: 0.0, remainingPaintExtent: 371.4, crossAxisExtent: 110.0, crossAxisDirection: AxisDirection.down, viewportMainAxisExtent: 381.4, remainingCacheExtent: 621.4, cacheOrigin: 0.0)
...  geometry: SliverGeometry(scrollExtent: -10.0, hidden, maxPaintExtent: -10.0)
...    scrollExtent: -10.0
...    hidden
...    maxPaintExtent: -10.0
...  no children current live
RenderObject: RenderSliverGrid#ee36d relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
constraints: SliverConstraints(AxisDirection.right, GrowthDirection.forward, ScrollDirection.idle, scrollOffset: 0.0, remainingPaintExtent: 371.4, crossAxisExtent: 110.0, crossAxisDirection: AxisDirection.down, viewportMainAxisExtent: 381.4, remainingCacheExtent: 621.4, cacheOrigin: 0.0)
geometry: SliverGeometry(scrollExtent: -10.0, hidden, maxPaintExtent: -10.0)
scrollExtent: -10.0
hidden
maxPaintExtent: -10.0
no children current live

## ======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
SliverGeometry is not valid: The "maxPaintExtent" is less than the "paintExtent".
The RenderSliver that returned the offending geometry was: RenderSliverPadding#d3dd8 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
constraints: SliverConstraints(AxisDirection.right, GrowthDirection.forward, ScrollDirection.idle, scrollOffset: 0.0, remainingPaintExtent: 381.4, crossAxisExtent: 130.0, crossAxisDirection: AxisDirection.down, viewportMainAxisExtent: 381.4, remainingCacheExtent: 631.4, cacheOrigin: 0.0)
geometry: SliverGeometry(scrollExtent: 10.0, paintExtent: 20.0, maxPaintExtent: 10.0, cacheExtent: 20.0)
scrollExtent: 10.0
paintExtent: 20.0
maxPaintExtent: 10.0
cacheExtent: 20.0
padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0)
textDirection: ltr
child: RenderSliverGrid#ee36d relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
parentData: paintOffset=Offset(10.0, 10.0) (can use size)
constraints: SliverConstraints(AxisDirection.right, GrowthDirection.forward, ScrollDirection.idle, scrollOffset: 0.0, remainingPaintExtent: 371.4, crossAxisExtent: 110.0, crossAxisDirection: AxisDirection.down, viewportMainAxisExtent: 381.4, remainingCacheExtent: 621.4, cacheOrigin: 0.0)
geometry: SliverGeometry(scrollExtent: -10.0, hidden, maxPaintExtent: -10.0)
scrollExtent: -10.0
hidden
maxPaintExtent: -10.0
no children current live
The relevant error-causing widget was:
SliverPadding file:///Users/gagansingh/FlutterProjects/firebase_app/lib/fullImageView/PortfolioGallarySubPage.dart:182:29
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderSliverPadding#d3dd8 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
constraints: SliverConstraints(AxisDirection.right, GrowthDirection.forward, ScrollDirection.idle, scrollOffset: 0.0, remainingPaintExtent: 381.4, crossAxisExtent: 130.0, crossAxisDirection: AxisDirection.down, viewportMainAxisExtent: 381.4, remainingCacheExtent: 631.4, cacheOrigin: 0.0)
geometry: SliverGeometry(scrollExtent: 10.0, paintExtent: 20.0, maxPaintExtent: 10.0, cacheExtent: 20.0)
scrollExtent: 10.0
paintExtent: 20.0
maxPaintExtent: 10.0
cacheExtent: 20.0
padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0)
textDirection: ltr
child: RenderSliverGrid#ee36d relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
parentData: paintOffset=Offset(10.0, 10.0) (can use size)
constraints: SliverConstraints(AxisDirection.right, GrowthDirection.forward, ScrollDirection.idle, scrollOffset: 0.0, remainingPaintExtent: 371.4, crossAxisExtent: 110.0, crossAxisDirection: AxisDirection.down, viewportMainAxisExtent: 381.4, remainingCacheExtent: 621.4, cacheOrigin: 0.0)
geometry: SliverGeometry(scrollExtent: -10.0, hidden, maxPaintExtent: -10.0)
scrollExtent: -10.0
hidden
maxPaintExtent: -10.0
no children current live
RenderObject: RenderSliverPadding#d3dd8 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
constraints: SliverConstraints(AxisDirection.right, GrowthDirection.forward, ScrollDirection.idle, scrollOffset: 0.0, remainingPaintExtent: 381.4, crossAxisExtent: 130.0, crossAxisDirection: AxisDirection.down, viewportMainAxisExtent: 381.4, remainingCacheExtent: 631.4, cacheOrigin: 0.0)
geometry: SliverGeometry(scrollExtent: 10.0, paintExtent: 20.0, maxPaintExtent: 10.0, cacheExtent: 20.0)
scrollExtent: 10.0
paintExtent: 20.0
maxPaintExtent: 10.0
cacheExtent: 20.0
padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0)
textDirection: ltr
child: RenderSliverGrid#ee36d relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
parentData: paintOffset=Offset(10.0, 10.0) (can use size)
constraints: SliverConstraints(AxisDirection.right, GrowthDirection.forward, ScrollDirection.idle, scrollOffset: 0.0, remainingPaintExtent: 371.4, crossAxisExtent: 110.0, crossAxisDirection: AxisDirection.down, viewportMainAxisExtent: 381.4, remainingCacheExtent: 621.4, cacheOrigin: 0.0)
geometry: SliverGeometry(scrollExtent: -10.0, hidden, maxPaintExtent: -10.0)
scrollExtent: -10.0
hidden
maxPaintExtent: -10.0
no children current live

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
SliverGeometry is not valid: The "maxPaintExtent" is less than the "paintExtent".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove :    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
Then Add Physics Your Problem Will be Solved .

```
 CustomScrollView(
                        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
                          slivers: <Widget>[
                            SliverPadding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              sliver: _buildContent(urls),
                            )
```

Comment: error gone but now it is not scrolling as there are more images which needed to be displayed

Comment: I tried Bouncing scroll physics and now it is scrolling vertical and I am trying to do horizontal